# Debug error when calling a Storyboard to Start

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, animation

I have some storyboards in XAML (WPF Project) and I´m calling them from the VB code with this:

```
Dim ServiceOff As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("ServiceStopped"), Storyboard)
ServiceOff.Begin()
```

I´m getting the following error when trying to build:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Begin' accepts this number of arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered in your other question.

You need to call ServiceOff.Begin(me) if you're not using .NET 3.5 **SP1**

Comment: Thanks, seems to accept it that way but I´m getting tons of other errors and I think I messed up somewhere else. It´s a simple test app so I´ll start over in a cleaner way. Thanks again for the help! Oh, and sorry for the double post, though you couldn't see the new comments on old posts. thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'll fix up your question too.